# How to show icons in QML

Tags: qml

I am new to QML and trying to set an icon for a desktop application, but I am confused about how to do it.  I can't find this information in the documentation or anywhere.

Comment: Which platform are you on? For instance, if you're on Windows, you ought to supply an `AppIcon.ico`, `Resources.rc` with `ICON` resource defined, etc. i.e. it has to comply with a Windows app and include Windows assets. The answer will change dependent on platform.

Comment: Which icon are you talking about? The application icon which is visible in docks or the WM, the window icon or an icon shown in a QML application? Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/appicon.html

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add below code in your main.cpp file

```
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("qrc:/icon.png"));
```